# What IP/ports should be opened for Docker Hub?

Tags: networking, firewall, docker

Given our client's restrictions, we cannot have our VMs completely open to the internet. However, we sometimes need to pull Docker images from Docker Hub.

We can white-list IP addresses and ranges, and ports; but no hostnames.

I've looked everywhere I could but did not find any IP list from where Docker downloads images when running commands such as `docker pull redis`. Has anyone had such problem?

I checked out the question: [Docker unable to pull images](https://superuser.com/questions/1045245/docker-unable-to-pull-images), but https://index.docker.io, unsurprisingly, resolves to another IP.

Comment: Check and links there within with relevant content: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399671/add-dockerhub-ip-addresses-on-whitelist

Comment: Oh, I didn't find that one! Thanks so much!